# Calling Default Phonegap Back Button Handler

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, cordova

I have a phonegap app that requires I capture the back button.  This works swimmingly but when I am at the main screen and the back button is pressed I want to call the original event handler and let the app close or do whatever comes naturally to the platform with such a press. I know I can tell the app to quit but understand this is bad form for iPhone apps.

No matter what I try (and I have tried many things)  I cannot get the original handler to fire.  Any advice?

In my code I have a switch statement inside my backbutton event handler that directs the app as needed to the effect of:

```
switch blahBlah
{
    case 'this' :
        doThis() ;
        break;
    case 'main' :
        // What do I do here that is well behaved for all platforms??? 
        break;
    default:
        doFoo() ;
}
```

Comment: How would the backbutton handler fire in the iPhone if there is no hardware back button? Once you think about that, you can forget about handling it for the iPhone and handle it for Android and WP7. Read the Phonegap docs about the event and see which platforms it applies to. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Detect whenever you land on the main screen and remove your custom event handler.

```
document.removeEventListener( "backbutton", function(){}, false );
```

and add the event listener on the other pages (or sections).

```
document.addEventListener( "backbutton", OverrideBackButton, false );
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, at least not on Android.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've used and it seems to work fine for my needs

```
        function pageinit() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceInfo, true);
        }


        function deviceInfo() {
            document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackButton, true);
        } 

        function onBackButton(e) {
            try{
                var activePage = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id');

                if(activePage == 'Options'){
                    closeOptions();
                } else if(activePage == 'Popup'){
                    closePopup();
                } else if(activePage == 'HomePage'){

                function checkButtonSelection(iValue){
                    if (iValue == 2){
                            navigator.app.exitApp();
                        }
                    }

                e.preventDefault();
                navigator.notification.confirm(
                    "Are you sure you want to EXIT the program?",
                    checkButtonSelection,
                    'EXIT APP:',
                    'Cancel,OK');
                } else {
                     navigator.app.backHistory();
                }
            } catch(e){ console.log('Exception: '+e,3); }
        }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This is the best answer, I have searched for the same question for so long, but couldn't find anything to work until I came accross this, thank you Sir!

Answer (score 2):

Cordova 7.x, at least on Android, doesn't seem to properly update the override state. As a consequence, **[@SHANK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14333820/1090166)** doesn't work anymore.

As a workaround, you can disable back button overriding manually, resulting in default behavior:

```
navigator.app.overrideBackbutton(false);
```

To re-active custom handling, analogously do:

```
navigator.app.overrideBackbutton(true);
```

*I filed [a bug report on Apache's issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13947) regarding this.*

Comment: Should you install any plugin or something else?