# 'backbutton' event fired when navigating to a page

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQM/Phonegap and I'm trying to get control over Android's back button. This is a simplified version of a function I built:

```
var currFunc = undefined;
function setButton () {
    var func = arguments[0];

    document.removeEventListener('backbutton', currFunc, false);
    currFunc = func;
    document.addEventListener('backbutton', currFunc, false);
}
```

I now call `setButton()` on every `pagebeforeshow` event to unset any handlers. On, say, Page B, I now call `setButton(function() { alert(1); });`.
First, this seems to work: Nothing happens on Page A, clicking the button on Page B will cause the alert. So far so good. But now, when I'm back on Page A and I click on a button that gets me to Page B again, it will already trigger the alert.

I'm confused. The listener should a) be unset anyway and b) only fire when the phone's backbutton is pressed, not when simply navigating within the app.

Does anyone have information or ideas on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of PhoneGap are you using? As this may be a bug fixed in a later release.

Comment: I'm using Phonegap Build without specifying a version, so it should be the latest one.

Comment: I also took this over to the PG Community now: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/backbutton_event_fires_when_navigating?rfm=1

Comment: I can't see a need to remove the event listener and re-add it back every time.  Take a look at an answer I gave on using the back button [jquery mobile, browser back button navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569389/jquery-mobile-browser-back-button-navigation/12570585#12570585) I pretty much use this structure in every Phonegap project I've done.  Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm aware of this method, but I have a few problems with it. First of all, it'd require me to have all backbutton-navigation in one place and all soft-button navigation in another place. But moreover, I need to do more than just navigating through pages. For example, I open divs that I want to close using the backbutton. I could check to see whether the div is visible and so on, but it feels dirty. Plus I'm curious to know why the above method doesn't work when it should. Thanks, though – I was gonna use that method if I can't get mine to work.

Comment: I ended up doing it in the manner of Chris' linked post. You could even say it's nice to have all this stuff in one place, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still don't know why the original code didn't work, but using the approach as mentioned in the comments works.